# MongoDb EnsureIndex looks have a bug

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I am battling strange behavior of index creation from hours. I am trying to re-build my sample datas so i drop my collection before insert new datas and before insert new datas i create indexes again like below.

```
db.GetCollection("Posts").EnsureIndex("Name","Title","Owner");
```

After that i am trying to Execute sorted Query but MongoDb throws exception and says that

> QueryFailure flag was too much data for sort() with no index.  add an index or specify a smaller limit

But if i put this line code `db.GetCollection("Post").EnsureIndex("Name");` before execute query, it works without problem. Then i have realized that if i use this before rebuild datas it works. There should to be a bug in overloading method or something i have missed.

I am using 10Gen .net driver version 1.2 and i have checked which indexes exist before execure query. Here it is

```
db.GetCollection("Posts").EnsureIndex("Name","Title","Owner");
db.GetIndexes();//result

[0]: { "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "ns" : "Posts", "name" : "_id_" }
[1]: { "v" : 1, "key" : { "Name" : 1, "Title" : 1, "Owner" : 1 }, "ns" : "Posts", "name" : "Name_1_Title_1_Owner_1_" }

db.GetCollection("Posts").EnsureIndex("Title") // i call this for other indexes too
db.GetIndexes();
```

> ```
> [0]: { "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "ns" : "Posts", "name" : "_id_" }
> [1]: { "v" : 1, "key" : { "Name" : 1 }, "ns" : "Posts", "name" : "Name_1" }
> [2]: { "v" : 1, "key" : { "Title" : 1 }, "ns" : "Posts", "name" : "Title_1" }
> [4]: { "v" : 1, "key" : { "Owner" : 1 }, "ns" : "Posts", "name" : "Owner_1" }
> ```

Comment: Reproduce in shell. If that works either you're doing something wrong or the driver you're using has issues.

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell from your example exactly what you think isn't working.

One thing to keep in mind is that EnsureIndex only knows what's going on within your own process. So if you remove an index or drop a collection using the mongo shell EnsureIndex won't pick up on that. You can use CreateIndex instead of EnsureIndex if you want to make sure the index exists regardless of what other processes might have done in the meantime.

Let me know if you can provide more details on how to reproduce what you are seeing.